# How to Flow Drain suspended Flows?

Tags: devops, corda

I understand that I can do `setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled` to stop new flows and to let the older suspended or current work-in-process flows complete. I am satisfied about the current work-in-process flows.

The reason that the older flows are suspended is because they are waiting for some other counterparty flows in the network to complete. 
Unless the counterparty node comes alive or sorts its issues, the flow drain is incomplete.

`CordaRPCOps.stateMachinesFeed.snapshot.size` would be non-zero. This means there are pending and waiting flows.

If the flow has not completed its course, would I be indefinitely stopping the node for the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 3.1, you would proceed as follows:

- Shut down the node
- Clear the `NODE_CHECKPOINTS` table
- For each row in the `VAULT_STATES` table:

  - Set `LOCK_ID` to `null`
  - Set `LOCK_TIMESTAMP` to `null`
- Update the node
- Restart the node

In Corda 4+, a `CordaRPCOps.killFlow` API will be introduced to kill suspended flows.

Comment: Should I also notify all the participants of the suspended flow to do the same ?